# ModelForm always return false when using ModelChoiceField in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

Models.py

```
class SysMcc(models.Model):
mcc_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
mcc_stype = models.CharField(max_length=100)
mcc_code = models.CharField(max_length=4)
```

Form.py

```
class MccTypeForm(ModelForm):
mcc_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SysMcc.objects.values_list('mcc_type', flat=True),initial=0, )

class Meta:
    model = SysMcc
    fields = ('mcc_type',)
```

View.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form_mcc = MccTypeForm(request.POST)
        if form_mcc.is_valid():

           ...
```

**First question**

When I display **mcc_type** in template using this:

```
 mcc_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SysMcc.objects.values_list('mcc_type', flat=True),initial=0, )
```

Templates look like

```
<option value="apple">apple</option>
<option value="google">google</option>
```

Which value is also **mcc_type**, now I want to set the value is **mcc_code**, like this:

```
<option value="1">apple</option>
<option value="2">google</option>
```

**Second question**

if form_mcc.is_valid() always return false so I can't keep going

Answer (score 0):

```
queryset=SysMcc.objects.values_list('mcc_type', flat=True)
```

This is not a queryset, if you want to fetch only mcc_type and id , then you have to do like;

```
queryset=SysMcc.objects.only('id', 'mcc_type')
```

Comment: Thanks, bro.When I use queryset=SysMcc.objects.only('id', 'mcc_type'), I get the queryset.but when I use form_mcc = MccTypeForm() to display my form with choice in field mcc_type.I only get the object like **SysMcc_Deferred_description_mcc_code_mcc_stype_oe1a4788ddc249748553cecbefd051522 object**, but I want to display the value of mcc_type directly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Display value in select

Override `__str__` in your Model:

```
class SysMcc(models.Model):
   mcc_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   mcc_stype = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   mcc_code = models.CharField(max_length=4)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.mcc_type
```

and use the queryset as described by Geo Jacob:

```
queryset=SysMcc.objects.only('id', 'mcc_type')
```

or just plain: `queryset=SysMcc.objects`

#### Form Valid

To know why `is_valid()` returns `False`, it's best to simply print out all the errors for the form and for each form field. There is a good chance that the problem is not what you think it is. Instead, there might be a field that you did not want to include but that Django thinks is required and should be set. Looking at your Model, all of the fields are required.